# CakePhp 2x Is enabling helpers still needed?

Tags: php, cakephp

for example if i want to use the HtmlHelper and the FormHelper i would enable them in my controller like this

```
class PostsController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

    public function index() {
    $this->set('posts', $this->Post->find('all'));
}
}
```

But, when i erase that line, i can still use the helpers in my views like this :

```
 <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $post['Post']['id']; ?></td>
            <td>
                 <!-- It works -->
                <?php echo $this->Html->link($post['Post']['title'],
                    array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'view', $post['Post']['id'])); ?>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $post['Post']['created']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($post); ?>
```

So, why would i enable them if it works whitout enabling it ?

Comment: In Cakephp 2.x, form, html helpers by default enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CakePHP, Html and Form are default helpers. So, these two will be loaded even if you don't write this line:

```
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
```

However, if you want to use any other helper (e.g Js, Time etc), you need to declare that, along with these two default helpers.

```
public $helpers = array('Js', 'Time'); // Incorrect approach as it will overwrite the default helpers
public $helpers = array('Form', 'Html', 'Js', 'Time'); // Correct approach
```

> If you need to enable a helper for all controllers, add the name of the helper to the `$helpers` array in `/app/Controller/AppController.php` (or create it if not present). Remember to include the default Html and Form helpers:

Reference: [CakePHP 2.x Helpers](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html)

Comment: Thanks ! It makes a lot of sens. I was trying to look where it was being enabled whitout my consent haha

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you have already enable those helpers in App Controller. As App controller is extended in each controller thats why those helpers are still working for you.

Comment: No i didn't enabled them anywhere !